# What network will Windows 10 resolve hostname to?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns, hosts-file

So I have a Windows 10 professional computer connected to multiple networks, one is a router with internet access, and then multiple network cameras and other hardware. Le

On the router there are two other computers intended to function as "slaves" to do various computing, so the computer in question is named "Master".

In Windows 7 and before I could set up a hosts file on all 3 computer defining the IP addresses of the computers,

```
192.168.173.10  master
192.168.173.11  worker-1
192.168.173.12  worker-2
```

However this no longer works in Windows 10. What happens instead is when pinging (or asking Windows to resolve "master" via APIs) it returns an IPv6 address (presumably to LocalHost). Then after turning off IPv6 it returns the IP to one of Camera networks, e.g 192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.100.

ipconfig /displayDNS returns (before IPv6 was disabled via regedit, after that the first entry is gone)

```
master
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : Master
Record Type . . . . . : 28
Time To Live  . . . . : 1200
Data Length . . . . . : 16
Section . . . . . . . : Question
AAAA Record . . . . . : ::1


master
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : Master
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 1200
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Question
A (Host) Record . . . : 192.168.0.1


Record Name . . . . . : Master
Record Type . . . . . : 1
Time To Live  . . . . : 1200
Data Length . . . . . : 4
Section . . . . . . . : Question
A (Host) Record . . . : 192.168.173.10
```

Now this problem can be "worked around" by changing the name of the computer to NOT match that in the hostfile, ie by renaming the computer master-TMP. But this has other consequences and I would really like to avoid this.

So my question is why does it prioritize the network specified in the hosts file **last**, why is it resolving the name to every connected network and is there any way of changing this?

Does anyone have an idea what has *changed* in Windows 10 (Perhaps also in Windows 8, not tested that) from Windows 7 and Vista/XP that you can no longer use your own hostname in hosts.

Please ask if I have forgotten to mention anything of importance.